# How can I print a C double bit-by-bit to see the low-level representation?

Tags: c, double, bit

I want to learn how the computer represents the `double` type in bit, but the `&` and `|` bit operators can't use `double`. And `memcpy(&d, &src, 8)` also doesn't seem to work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show which part of your homework you've already written, and which part isn't working the way you expect?

Comment: What do you mean the memcpy doesn't work? Are you using the right size? Are src and d doubles? If so you should use memcpy(&d, &src, sizeof(double)); ... Please specify more of the problem with memcpy.

Comment: @Jonathan Feinberg Why do you assume anyone curious about low-level language details is cheating on homework? As someone who was always curious about things like this when I was first learning to program, I find this attitude really irritating.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/aspyct/3194882 This one actually gives the bits as asked for rather than bytes as in many answers.

Answer (score 6):

Here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    double decker = 1.0;
    unsigned char * desmond = (unsigned char *) & decker;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof (double); i++) {
         printf ("%02X ", desmond[i]);
    }
    printf ("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

You can try it: http://codepad.org/onHnAcnC

Comment: Shouldn't that `8` be `sizeof(double)`?

Comment: sbi: Should, but should also pose no problem, as `double` is defined to be 64 bits long. Ok, architectures with non-8-bit bytes are another matter, then :-)

Comment: +1 for the variable names, despite the spelling error (it's Dekker).

Comment: @Johannes Rössel: The ISO standard for C defines no such thing. It merely requires that every float can be exactly represented as a double, and that every double can be exactly represented as a long double. That merely implies that sizeof double is at least equal to sizeof float. An implementation is free to use whatever size. On machines with and FPU, it is likely that the size is determined by the hardware implementation. In the 16-bit dsPIC compiler I am currently using double is 32-bits unless you specify 64-bits with a compiler option.

Comment: Possibly Johannes is confusing Standard C with IEEE 754. The latter does define a double-precision floating point as 64 bits. C's "double" doesn't have to be 754's "double-precision", but they have similar names for a reason.

Comment: @fvu: no it's double DECKER not DEKKER.

Comment: But (perhaps confusingly), it's Desmond Dekker: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desmond_Dekker

Comment: nice example, but actually it is "byte-by-byte" and not "bit-by-bit" as was asked for

Answer (score 2):

```
union {
  double  d;
  unsigned char c[sizeof(double)];
} d;

int main(int ac, char **av) {
  int i;
  char s1[80], s2[80];

  d.d = 1.0;
  for(i = 0; i < sizeof d; ++i) {
    sprintf(s1 + i * 3, " %02x", d.c[i]);
    sprintf(s2 + i * 3, " %02x", d.c[sizeof d - 1 - i]);
  }
  printf("%s\n%s\n", s1, s2);
  return 0;
}

$ ./a.out
00 00 00 00 00 00 f0 3f
3f f0 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Or you could just [read about the IEEE 754 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985), which specifies representation.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985

Answer (score 1):

A particular bit layout by itself is meaningless. Suppose I have the following: `1101`

Maybe I say that is unsigned and it represents the value 13.

Maybe it is signed and that high bit signifies that the value is a negative which means it is now -5.

Consider further that I consider the high two bits to be a base and the low two bits to be an exponent, then I get the value 3.

You see, it isnt the storage, its the interpretation. Read up on how floating point values are represented and interpreted; it will serve you much better than seeing how the bits are packed.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't going to be very enlightening unless you also know a bit about typical IEEE FP representations.

Most likely the way your machine represents doubles is spelled out [here](http://www.psc.edu/general/software/packages/ieee/ieee.php).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> /* memmove */
int main(void) {
  unsigned char dontdothis[sizeof (double)];
  double x = 62.42;

  printf("%f\n", x);
  memmove(&dontdothis, &x, sizeof dontdothis);
  /* examine/change the array dontdothis */
  dontdothis[sizeof x - 1] ^= 0x80;
  /* examine/change the array dontdothis */
  memmove(&x, &dontdothis, sizeof dontdothis);
  printf("%f\n", x);
  return 0;
}
```

The result is

```
62.420000
-62.420000
```

Comment: I think the OP is looking for output with 64 0s or 1s, representing the 64 bits used to encode a double float.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to convert the `double` to a `long long` (assuming `sizeof(double) == sizeof(long long)`) without changing binary representation. This can be achieved by one of the following methods:

- cast: `double a; long long b = *((long long *)&a);`
- union: `union { double a ; long long b };`

Comment: The cast has undefined result, because of type-punning and the strict aliasing rules. Sometimes this kind of thing actually does go wrong, and with enough optimisation some compilers will read b before a has been initialised (assuming it is initialised), although you might be OK with a case this simple. Converting through a union is undefined behaviour (except in certain cases of which this isn't one), but in practice no sensible compiler writer will let it break, since too much code uses it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [bitfields](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/bitfields.html).  Armed with such a structure and knowledge of how a double is supposed to be stored on your computer you can very easily print out the different parts of the internal representation of the double.  A bit like they do [here](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node13.html#SECTION001321000000000000000).